# Insert and Registration data not show in database table visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2019

I'm making a enrollment system using visual studio 2019 and SQL server management studio 2008.When i tried to click insert button 'Inserted Successfully' and there's no errors.When i tried to click registration button 'Record Updated Successfully'  and also there's no errors.But when i opened the database and refresh the database table there's no data in the data table.Any support for this issue much appreciated.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

        try
        {

            //taking data from the GUI

            string ID = textBox1.Text;
            string RegistrationNumber = textBox1.Text;
            string StudentName = textBox2.Text;
            string DateOfBirth = dateTimePicker1.Text;
            String Age = textBox3.Text;
            String Gender;
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                Gender = "Male";
            }
            else
            {
                Gender = "Female";
            }
            string ContactNumber = textBox4.Text;
            ;


            if (textBox1.Text == "" && textBox2.Text == "" && textBox3.Text == "" && textBox4.Text == "")

            {
                MessageBox.Show("Complete the Missing Data");
            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Click on the selected item after selecting a course");
            }
            else
            {
                string course = (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null) ? comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() : "";
                MessageBox.Show("Student Inserted Successfully!!");
                string constr = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbo.Table_1"] != null) ? ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbo.Table_1"].ConnectionString : "";
                connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                    con.ConnectionString = constr;

            }
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Table_1(ID, Registration Number, Student Name, Date of Birth, Age, Gender, Contact Number, Course Enrolled In) VALUES(@ID,@RegistrationNumber,@StudentName,@DateOfBirth,@Age,@Gender,@ContactNumber)", connection);
            
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            com.Connection = con;
            
            com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Table_1 WHERE ID = @ID;";
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox1.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationNumber", textBox1.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", textBox2.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", dateTimePicker1.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", textBox3.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", textBox4.Text);

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            com.ExecuteReader();
            com.Dispose();


        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }


    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ID = textBox1.Text;
        if (ID == null) ;
        if (textBox1.Text=="" || textBox2.Text=="" || textBox3.Text=="" || textBox4.Text=="")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Missing Details");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully!!");
            string constr = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbo.Table_1"] != null) ? ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbo.Table_1"].ConnectionString : "";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                con.ConnectionString = constr;
            if(con.State==ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            
            String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM dbo.Table_1 WHERE ID =@ID";
            
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con) ;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
            int Id;
            if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out Id))
            {
                // Report problem to your user
                return;
            }
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            
            while (sdr.Read())


            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(sdr["count"]) == 1)
                {
                    button2.Enabled = false;
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    button2.Enabled = true;
                    button1.Enabled = false;
                 }


            }

            {

            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post images code or any other text. Copy the original text to your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, I find that you defined the SqlCommand.CommandText two times.

Please try to modify your code to the following.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
 command.Connection = connection;
 command.CommandText = "insert into Student(ID,StudentName,DateOfBirth)values(@ID,@StudentName,@DateOfBirth)";
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(ID));
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", textBox2.Text);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", DateOfBirth

);
```

Also, please note that we should place the `MessageBox.Show` after the code  `com.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

Here is a code example you could refer to, based on my test, it works well.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string ID = textBox1.Text;
                string StudentName = textBox2.Text;
                DateTime DateOfBirth = dateTimePicker1.Value;
                string constr = "sttr";
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr);
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "insert into Student(ID,StudentName,DateOfBirth)values(@ID,@StudentName,@DateOfBirth)";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(ID));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", textBox2.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", DateOfBirth);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("success inserted");
                connection.Close();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
          
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ID = textBox1.Text;
            string constr = "str";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr);
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM Student WHERE ID =@ID";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(ID));
            SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(sdr["count"]) == 1)
                {
                    button2.Enabled = false;
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    button2.Enabled = true;
                    button1.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully!!");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After the below line

com.connection = con;

add below code

com.executenonquery();

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. same issue, nothing showing in database table